# multiple rows in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my python code below :

```
import glob
lines = []

for filename in glob.glob('*.sql'):
    with open (filename, 'rt') as in_file:

        for line in in_file:
            lines.append(line)

    #for element in lines:
    #   print(element) 


enumerate(lines)
#print(list(enumerate(lines)))

#for linenum, line in enumerate(lines):
#   print(linenum, line)



substr = "NO FALLBACK" # Substring to search for, in this case a single character 
for linenum, line in enumerate(lines): 
    index = 0 
    str = lines[linenum] 
    while index < len(str):
        index = str.find(substr, index) 
        if index == -1:
            break 
        print("FileName:",filename, "Line: ", linenum, "Index: ", index) 
        index += len(substr)
```

HOWEVER,

my output isn't coming correct.

i have two files. 
f1.sql and f2.sql are in the directory. 
files are being read. 
but the desired output isn't coming.

i want if the word NO FALLBACK is written in the file then that file name, line Number and index should come.

but my code keeps iterating over the number of lines in the file.

below is the output coming:

```
('FileName:', 'f1.sql', 'Line: ', 4, 'Index: ', 71)
('FileName:', 'f1.sql', 'Line: ', 5, 'Index: ', 47)
```

the file name is same . this is wrong. and the line number is addition to the last line number, which is wrong again.

**f1.sql**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------
------------------------            Back Up Daily Fact          ------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE MULTISET TABLE DP_SDM.NETWRK_OUTG_USG_DLY_SNAP_FCT_BKP20170203 ,NO FALLBACK ,
```

**f2.sql**

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE dp_tmp_planning.nea_kqi ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
```

Comment: Why `str = lines[linenum]` when you already have `line`? Why the random `enumerate` by itself?

Comment: enumurate will show me the number of line

Comment: Why do you expect to get a different file name each time? Do you do anything to associate the file name with the search?

Comment: You should consider indenting your code differently then.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking for `substr` *within* the outermost `for` loop--not in a separate loop, as you currently have it organized. That way, you can search one file at a time, and `filename` reflects the current file name that you are searching.

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    lines = []

    with open (filename, 'rt') as in_file:
        lines = list(in_file)

    substr = "NO FALLBACK" # Substring to search for, in this case a single character
    for linenum, line in enumerate(lines):
        index = 0
        while index < len(line):
            index = line.find(substr, index)
            if index == -1:
                break
            print("FileName:",filename, "Line: ", linenum, "Index: ", index)
            index += len(substr)
```

**EDIT**

Use regular expressions for more powerful matching. This will let you search for multiple non-overlapping matches on each string. (It also simplifies your code, in general)    import glob
    import re

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    lines = []

    with open (filename, 'rt') as in_file:
        lines = list(in_file)

    SUBSTR_REGEX = r'NO FALLBACK|READ' 

    for linenum, line in enumerate(lines):
        matches = re.finditer(SUBSTR_REGEX, line, re.IGNORECASE)
        for match in matches:
            print("FileName:",filename, "Line: ", linenum, "Index: ", match.start())
```

Comment: `lines = list(in_file)` would be nice too.

Comment: Also, remove `str = lines[linenum]` and use `line` in place of `str`

Comment: @MadPhysicist plenty of things to fix. Just trying to get to the heart of the issue.

Comment: thanks guys!

also, can i find multiple strings in that line ?

Comment: @waterboy5281 how to i add more substrings or string in substr like if i want to find NO FallBACk or READ ONLY in the lines

Comment: @waterboy5281 also its case sensitive, if there are FALLBACK or fallBack it wont count as 1 , right?

Comment: added `re.IGNORECASE` and modified the regex slightly. If you want to make further enhancements, I recommend learning about the `re` package and playing with regular expressions at [regex101](https://regex101.com/)